# EventHandler with return type

Tags: java, vaadin

How use `@EventHandler` with return type

Call server side and check it return type

```
  @EventHandler
  public boolean doTest{}

        _test() {
          if (this.$.doTest()) {
            alert("Good");
          } else {
            alert("Not Good");
          }
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is not directly possible since calling the `doTest` method on the server happens asynchronously, whereas `this.$.doTest()` must return right away to avoid locking up the entire browser.

Instead, you'd need to make your `doTest()` implementation call a function using something like `this.getElement().callFunction("testResult", true)` and then implement `testResult` as a client-side function.

Comment: Hm In my example I do client call server. In your server call client. Right?

Comment: My example would be based on one explicit call in each direction, but I didn't show the client to server call since it would be basically the same as in your example.